# Property 'className' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript

Getting message -
[ts] Property 'className' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLUListElement>'.

Here is the code:

```
import { MouseEvent } from "react";

function ListGroup() {
  let items = ["New York", "Chicago", "Minnepolis", "Des Moines", "Tampa"];

  const handleClick = (event: MouseEvent) => console.log(event);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>List</h1>
      <ul className="list-group">
        {items.length === 0 && <p>No Items Found</p>}
        {items.map(item => (
          <li className="list-group-item" key={item} onClick={handleClick}>
            {item}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default ListGroup;
```

How do I get off this message for using className in the ul tag?

Comment: are u install required packages?
npm install @types/react --save-dev

Comment: Yes, still getting the message.

Comment: maybe you should check your tsconfig.json, should be somthing like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an issue. In TypeScript, be clear about the type of event you're handling. MouseEvent needs more details, like the type of element you're clicking on.
Here is a sample that should work fine, which specifies the event type.

```
  const handleClick = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement>) => {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.textContent);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks! But that's not my issue. The issue is the error message it is showing for the className for us tag.